# Having trouble closing my circle text

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, text-editing

I'm using Microsoft Powerpoint 2010 to make some text boxes for a slideshow. I know how to use the Transform section to make circular text shapes, but I'm having trouble making a complete circle. I'm making a "Saturday Night Live" type logos, only having 3 words in them. How can I complete or close the circle of text so that I don't have half a circle or the text doubled in the logo. I only want it to say the three words once and be a full circle.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to using the combination of the **correct font size**, **size of the text box**, and setting the **contour marker** (the purple diamond) correctly. There are three steps I'd try:

1. Make sure the purple contour marker is set to full circle - otherwise you'll end up with an arch instead. Move it around, and you'll see the two arches converge to a circle - that's what you want
2. Resize the text box to fit the space you want your final shape to take
3. Increase / decrease the font size to make the text occupy the full circumference of the circle, avoiding partial arches / doubled text

Does this help at all?